# TableTools for DataTables, with Rails 3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, tabletools

Stack Overflow has usually been good in regards to solutions, but I've been unable to find a solution to this problem.

I'm trying to setup TableTools with Datatables for my Rails application, but it's not working. Strangely enough, the website doesn't really help much with this so-called 'Plug-in'. The website states that you just add some 5 lines of script, but it doesn't work. After quite a few hours working on this, I discovered the DataTables debugger here:

http://debug.datatables.net/

After running that bookmark on my pages, I discovered that TableTools wasn't even being recognized as installed. I figured that was strange, since the files appear to be included with DataTables. So, I've moved the .js files for TableTools into /lib/assets/javascript/ directory. After changing the application.js file and application.css file to the following, TableTools was recognized as being installed:

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require TableTools
//= require ZeroClipboard
//= require_tree .
```

application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require jquery.ui.core
*= require jquery.ui.theme
*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
*= require dataTables/extras/TableTools
*= require dataTables/extras/TableTools_JUI
*= require_tree .
*/
```

Now, to the actual js.coffee file. I got DataTables to work perfectly fine, by itself, with this code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#artists').dataTable
  sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
  bJQueryUI: true
```

But, when I add the portion for TableTools, nothing changes. This is the change that I've made:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#artists').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bJQueryUI: true
    sDom: 'T<"clear"><"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-      clearfix"lfr>t<"fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix"ip>'
    oTableTools: {
    sSwfPath: "http://localhost:3000/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" }
```

This version of the js.coffee script includes the complete URL to where the swf file is located. I found on NUMEROUS pages that people were repeatedly saying that the pathing was wrong. This path can't get anymore correct, since I moved the swf folder into the Public directory and used this path. I tried it locally and it didn't work. I changed the URL to the Heroku site where I'm pushing the application, pushed it up, and it doesn't work there either.

Help me, Stack Overflow... you're my only hope.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough... after working on another problem, I accidentally fixed this. I think the problem came from having issues with Heroku and precompile. Since I'm using Devise, precompile has to be disabled. But, it can be run manually before pushing to Heroku. So, once I precompiled to fix another problem, the buttons were accessible.